# In caffe installation, where to set python path in vs studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Hi Im trying to install caffe deep learning tool box in windows.

I have to use it in python. I have so far completed first 2 steps mentioned in `https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows`

For python wrapper, it says
 `replace the python include and library path and compile.` .
I dont know where to set python include and library path in vs studio 2015.

I have also run `MainBuilder.sln` in `build_cpu_only` folder. It gives the error `cannot find config.lib`. I'm trying to install caffe for python in windows for several hours. Please help. A step by step simple procedure to install caffe on windows and use it in python will be highly appreciated.

Comment: good luck. please update if you manage to pull this through.

Comment: Do you use caffe in linux?

Comment: yes, I use caffe in Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: I'm installing in Ubuntu. I have to edit Makefile.config. I can't find where it is.

Comment: Is there any alternative of caffe? I have `prototxt` file and `caffemodel` file for pretrained network

Comment: you should have `Makefile.config.example` - copy it to `Makefile.config` and edit it according to your needs/configuration.

Comment: there are alternatives to caffe. You can checkout torch7, I believe there is a module that knows how to convert `caffemodel`+`prototxt` from caffe into a torch7 valid models.

Comment: Can torch7 work on windows too?

Comment: you tell me - I have no idea ;)

Comment: [torch7](http://torch.ch/). [install](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28054916/1714410). [convert caffe models](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe). Good luck.