# Deep neural network for windows

Tags: neural-network

I have some data that i would like to fit with a deep neural network. I only have windows. What program is the easiest to install and get working?
It would be nice if the installation does not require administrator rights on windows.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are beginning your adventure of neural networks and want something easy to start. You may try Neuroph. You can download it from Sourceforge:

http://neuroph.sourceforge.net

It comes with number of examples, source code, etc. There seems to be community of people who support it so it might be worth giving a go.

Other than that - there is a lot of software - like Python-based solutions. You may also want to look into this thread where guys try to install Torch on Windows ([How to install Torch on windows 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28054916/how-to-install-torch-on-windows-8-1))